# How to adjust 2 toolbars to fit parent width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have 2 `Toolbars` in the code below and I want to see them side by side. first should cover **80%** of the width and remaining should be covered by the second toolbar. How can I do that. I can hard code the width like **200dip /100 dip** but that does not work when I change mobile.. Screen bursts.

```html
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
```

Comment: you can use LinearLayout inside Toolbar

Comment: inside toolbar or inside app bar layout??  can you demonstrate an example?

Comment: Just play with the wieghtSum property of the LinearLayout...

Comment: it will depend on your need. can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? also provide screenshot if possible

Comment: Look I have an appbar layour and in it I am trying to fit 2 toolbars  side by side.   I have did that well..  But the width is ahrd coded. now I tried to get them in weights. I know I can use linear layout..  but what should be the structure?? like app bar layout tag and then linear layout and in it there should be toolbars??  or something else??

Comment: Use the <AppBarLayout>... <LinearLayout>..<Toolbar> <Toolbar>...</AppBarLayout>... </LinearLayout>

Comment: thanks much for the kind help

Comment: As to why your code is not working- It seems AppBar layout is vertical LinearLayout so you can scale the height not the width

Comment: @nimraasad ..Below m giving the answer .....Please check my solutiion

Comment: @nimraasad ..Happy to help you..Keep good coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below solution, it can help you

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
           </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need that, but you can wrap them in `LinearLayout` applying weights like these:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks much... and yes I did something like this.. i used linear layout inside my app bar and it also worked very well. Actually I am really new to android and development.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```